# How get list of 'parameters' from string using regular expressions?

Tags: php

I have the string with parameters like

> "Hello, %{user}. Please, give %{client} a knife".

So, please, I'm not familiar with regular expressions, and I need to have php construction which can get list of parameters from a string. Please, help me, I hope you can. Thank you.

Comment: Will you have to depend on someone else every time you need to maintain your own code too? This regular expression is quite simple. Give it a shot yourself and ask a question if you have specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Hello, %{user}. Please, give %{client} a knife".
preg_match_all("/%\{(.*?)\}/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```